# Strict usage of a holder class

Tags: c#

If I have a class, let's say Car.

```
class Car {
    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;
}
```

Now, when I have this class at this state, I'm implementing this on X number of places in my software. Later on, my boss says he also want to store the max speed of the car. By all means, he is a nice guy and should have his property added.

```
class Car {
    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;
    private int m_MaxSpeed;
}
```

With this workflow, we might have something like this after a while

```
class Car {
    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;
    private int m_MaxSpeed;
    private int m_Year;
    private List<Seats> m_Seats;
    private DateTime m_LatestCHeckup;
    private double m_GasUsage;
}
```

Which is ok, but the 1st and 2nd version of the class is already implemented with fewer properties. How can I make sure, that if I add a property on a object that property must be used on all other objects initiated from the same class?

EDIT: 
To clear it up.

I use this for my first car:

```
Car c = new Car();
c.m_Color = Color.White;
c.m_Passengers = 4;
```

and this for my 2nd car:

```
Car c2 = new Car();
c2.m_Color = Color.White;
c2.m_Passengers = 4;
c2.m_MaxSpeed=200;
```

and 3rd car

```
Car c3 = new Car();
c3.m_Color = Color.Green;
c3.m_Passengers = 8;
c3.m_MaxSpeed=180;
c3.m_Year = 2000;
c3.m_Seats = mySeatList;
c3.m_LatestCheckup = Datetime.Now;
c3.m_GasUsage=1.8;
```

I want to make sure that GasUsage is added on c and c2 when I've added it to the class. But c and c2 was created long time ago when GasUsage didnt exist. How do I prevent an object to not have all properties used? I might have one class, but 2000 objects.

The reason I want this behaviour is because I might loop through all the car objects and calculate for example how much gas they've used. Or similiar. If not all objects have a value in GasUsage that calc would fail.

Comment: What is the 'this' you're implementing in X number of places? You only need to change `Car` once. Are you trying to process all of its properties somewhere?

Comment: It depends what you mean with "_used_". Initialized? Read? Something else?

Comment: @lee I've updated my question. I hope it got clearer :)

Comment: @Adriano what I mean with "used" is that a property got a value. I dont want an object to be valid if not all properties are set with data of its type.

Comment: You can't force compiler to emit errors if some property isn't called. There are many solutions for this (all at run-time). What I usually prefer is to initialize everything to a common/valid value and then do a check first time you call a method (if (!IsFullyInitialized()) throw... It'll check at run-time but it's best you can do (well you may even force to pass all required parameters in constructor but IMO it's pretty terrible if you have a lot of them).

Comment: are you telling me you are to lazy to go edit all the places where you have initialised the variable to go and add the new properties? Or am i understanding you wrong?

Comment: @NicolasTyler IMO it's not the point to be lazy or not but to detect where you forget to do it. In your code and/or in code wrote by someone else

Comment: well surely the OP can just use Visual Studios `Find All References` feature to find all the places the class has been used.

Comment: Yes, I'm lazy! But as Adriano already pointed out. Its not for that reason I want to achieve this :) Thanks Adriano for your previous answer aswell!

Comment: @NicolasTyler I dont want to search through thousands of objects to manually see if I've done anything wrong. I take it you wouldn't want to do that either!

Comment: i wouldn't initialise thousands of objects.

Comment: Even if someone payed you to?

Comment: thats not the point. there is alternatives to typing the same thing 1000 times over.

Comment: @NicolasTyler You're way out of the topic now and I dont even know why. You're suggesting I'm creating thousands of objects manually, which I obviously dont. I dont think you understand the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have required properties that need to be initialised you should declare them in the constructor. Any optional values can be made into properties.

If you add any required properties to your `Car` class you should add them to the constructor, then the compilation will fail until previously-created values are fixed.

From your comment it looks like you want to add an interface with all the declared properties, then make them all constructor parameters in your implementing class:

```
public interface ICar {
    Color Color { get; }
    int Passengers { get; }
    ...
    double GasUsage { get; }
}

class Car : ICar {
    public Car(Color color, int passengers, int maxSpeed, ..., double gasUsage) {
        this.m_Color = color;
        this.m_Passengers = passengers;
        ...
        this.m_GasUsage
    }
    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;
}
```

Comment: This is kinda what I want, but I dont want to allow default values. I want what interfaces are to methods, but to properties.

Comment: @user3427831 - You can put properties in interfaces, see update.

Comment: I dont even know how I could have missed this.. But thanks mate! Street cred to you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 'Property must be used' means that you expect the instantiated objects to set a value for each of the new properties then you either change the constructor to require the new properties, set a default value for the new properties or raise an exception if a method on the object is called that requires a value to be set.

First version of the car class:

```
class Car
{
    public Car(Color mColor, int mPassengers)
    {
        m_Color = mColor;
        m_Passengers = mPassengers;
    }

    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;

}
```

Second version of the car class with constructor that has default value:

```
class Car
{
    public Car(Color mColor, int mPassengers, int mMaxSpeed = 130)
    {
        m_Color = mColor;
        m_Passengers = mPassengers;
        m_MaxSpeed = mMaxSpeed;
    }

    private Color m_Color;
    private int m_Passengers;
    private int m_MaxSpeed;

}
```

Comment: Can you make an example?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of this solution, but problem here is that everything doesnt have default values. Two cars of the same model can have different engines which results in different maxspeeds for example. Therefor, I need something more strict. Like, is this property set to a value? No? EXCEPTION IN YOUR FACE! :) Something like that atleast :)

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the class instances could also be done with an constructor that demands all properties; all instatiations would then become syntactically incorrect as soon as a new property is added.

Comment: Yes! Can I ask for an example?

Comment: My answer is basically the same as the answer by user904895.